# Нужен css-файл, который будет заменять css стили в WordPress плагинах

Tags: css, wordpress

Изменения в плагине "Mega main menu" заменяет. Все внесенные мои изменения в сss-файл данного плагина. Нужен плагин или способ? при котором css стили не менялись бы сами по себе.

Comment: Это вы что же, правили стили прямо файлах плагина?

Comment: Да, других способов пока не знаю

Comment: В родном кастомайзере есть доп. стили. Но всё рано дочерняя тема лучше

Answer (score 0):

Естественно, что при обновлении плагина все ваши правки, сделанные в файлах плагина, будут перезаписаны.

Для внесения правок, нечувствительных к обновлениям, следует создать [дочернюю тему](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html), и уже в её файл style.css (или дополнительные css-файлы) вносить изменения стилей плагинов и родительской темы. Файлы дочерней темы являются единственно надёжным местом хранения стилей и хуков, модифицирующих работу плагинов.